# Operator norm and largest singular value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $P$ is a $d \times d$ matrix. The textbook defines the operator norm (also the largest singular value) as
$$
||P||_{op}=\lambda_1 (P^{\top}P)^{1/2}
$$
What does $\lambda_1$ mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the largest (in absolute value/modulus) eigenvalue of your matrix. This is also called the spectral radius. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius

Comment: Thank you so much! If I understood correctly, the $||P||_{op}$ here is also a $d \times d$ matrix, right?

Comment: No, I think your textbook uses a weird notation for spectral radius, as in $\lambda_1$ is a function meant to extract the spectral radius from the matrix $P^T P$. So $\| P\|_{op}$ is a scalar, the square root of the spectral radius itself. See link: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OperatorNorm.html